GetExportedChatInvitesRequest method
I use telethon and GetExportedChatInvitesRequest method to get all invite-links for my public channel, the documentation (https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_exported_chat_invites.html#examples) says that both users and bots can use this request but when i run my script using bot there is an error
 An error occurred: The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by GetExportedChatInvitesRequest)
my code -
api_id = 123
api_hash = 'hash'
channel_id = 'id'
admin = 'admin_id'

bot = 'token'
async def main():
    async with TelegramClient('usage', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        await client.start(bot_token = bot)
        try:
            invites = await client(GetExportedChatInvitesRequest(
                peer = channel_id,
                admin_id = admin,
                revoked = False,
                limit = 100
            ))
            for links in invites.invites:
                print(f'link - {links.link}, how many users joined - {links.usage}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


import asyncio
asyncio.run(main())

can someone explain, what im doing wrong or this method really works only with users?

bots can't fetch this info. and the reference site is autogenerated, it says "Both users and bots may be able to", which is a default string when no manually specified usability is available.
